# LAG/LEAD function

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I tried to receive the previous Order date (one before the latest order) and I get NULLs.
Please see my code and screenshot of the results :
I use Adventureworks2019 DB version
**Screenshot**:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx7tj.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx7tj.png

```
    enter code here
With A 
AS
(Select customerid,Max(orderdate) as Maxdate 
From Sales.salesorderheader 
Group by CustomerID)
Select * from 
(
Select S.Salesorderid,S.CustomerID,P.Lastname,P.Firstname,S.OrderDate as 'Last Order',
lag(s.OrderDate) over(partition by S.customerID order by S.orderdate)as 'Previous Order',
Row_number() over(partition by S.customerID order by S.Orderdate ) as RS
From Sales.salesorderheader S Join A as AA
On AA.customerid= S.customerid  Join
Sales.Customer C on C.CustomerID = S.CustomerID  Join
Person.Person P on P.businessentityID=C.PersonID) s
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit your question and show the query that you used.  Sample data *in the question* as text is much, much better than an image.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: This is why using single quotes (`'`) for aliasing is a bad habit; because it makes people think that putting a literal string to reference a column works, when it does not.

Comment: Hi, I fixed it and still I see NULLs

Comment: Well, looking at your sample data, no customers have more than 1 order, so of course you'll get a `NULL`.

Comment: Who is Lucas? No one with that name has participated here.

Comment: ohh Im sorry @Larnu. I meant to you.   I fixed a bit my code and now I see all orders for each customer in the column Last Order. How can I edit my code in order to see the latest order and in the second column the previous order? I also add the screenshot of the expected answer

Answer (score 1):

Did you use this?

```
select o.*,
       lag(orderdate) over (partition by customerid order by orderdate) as prev_orderdate
from orders o;
```

Note that in the data in your image, no customer has ordered more than once, so there is no previous order date in that example.